# xsl-fo. Images not showing on PDF using xml apache graphics?

Tags: xml, image, apache, pdf, xsl-fo

I'm new in xsl-fo. When I run my application on localhost, the images showing on my pdf. But when I deploy the application on the server the images not showing.

All images in my project are in `src/main/resources/images` folder.
My xsl file is in `src/main/resources/images/xsl` folder.

All images are referenced in my xsl file by this.

```
  <fo:block margin-left="40mm" margin-right="2mm"
            margin-bottom="5mm">
            <fo:external-graphic                             
            src="url(file:src/main/resources/images/Image10.jpg)"
            content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit"
            scaling="uniform" />
   </fo:block>
```

Can some guides me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

`src/main/resources/images/Image10.jpg` is being located relative to the FO file (or relative to what you told the XSL Formatter to use as the base directory, or relative to an `xml:base` value).

Is there a `src/main/resources/images` directory on the server located relative to the FO file, if you run FOP on a file, or located relative to FOP's base directory if the FO doesn't exist as a file when you run FOP?

See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#graphic-not-displayed

Comment: I put images in src/main/resources/images and my xsl file  in src/main/resources/xsl . The both folders are on the classPath of my Maven Project.

Comment: Are you saying that arrangement of folders works for you or does not work?  I would be surprised if FOP used your Maven classpath, but I also don't know that much about how FOP works.